# Natural Isomorphism in Definition of Tangent Spaces

Tags: differential-geometry, category-theory

I was reading about Differentiable manifolds and stumbled upon a definition of a tangent space. Now, i know there are many definitions, but this concerns the definition via derivations on germs of smooth functions at a point p, that is:

Let $M$ be a differentiable manifold, $p$ $\in$ $M$, then let $\widetilde{F_p}$ be the algebra of germs of smooth functions at $p$.Then the tangent space at p: $T_p$ is then defined as derivations $\widetilde{F_p} \to \mathbb{R}$ (that is, linear functionals $v$ satisfying $v(fg) = f(p)v(g) + v(f)g(p)$)

Let $F_p$ be the ideal of functions that vanish on p (which is of course well defined on germ classes), and $F_p^2 = F_p F_p$ (product of ideals). My book then proves a (rather beautiful in my opinion) proposition that $T_p \cong (F_p/F_p^2)^*$ **naturally**

Of course in the context of linear algebra this means "without choosing a basis", but I'm wondering whether this can be made more formal by considering this as an actual natural isomorphism (between functors).

My first guess was that we can consider something like $p \mapsto T_p$ and $p \mapsto (F_p/F_p^2)^*$, and i think this works, but i don't think this result should depend on the manifold i'm considering (since we don't actually mention it ever)

So my question is: what is the most "canonical" pair of functors that makes this into a natural isomorphism?

Comment: These are both functors from the category of pointed smooth manifolds (with basepoint-preserving smooth maps) to the category of real vector spaces.

Comment: @JackLee What will the induced morphism be between these "linear germs functionals" (F_p^2/F_p)* be? I figure something to do with the derivative but i'm not quite getting it

Comment: Right, it's the derivative, since both of these spaces are just the tangent space! Specifically, a map $F$ induces a map on derivations by $(F_*d)(f)=d(f\circ F).$ Similarly, composing with $F$ preserves $F_p$ and $F_p^2$, so there's no problem defining the functors.

Comment: Suppose $F\colon M\to N$ is smooth and $F(p)=q$. If $u$ is a function defined on a neighborhood of $q$, let $[u]_q$ denote the equivalence class of its germ in $F_q/F_q^2$. Then the functor you want sends $F$ to the map $F_*\colon (F_p/F_p^2)^* \to (F_q/F_q^2)^*$ defined by $(F_*\phi) \big([u]_q\big) = \phi\big( [u\circ F]_p\big)$. There's a bit of work to be done in showing that this is well-defined, but that's the idea.

Comment: What text book are you reading from?

Comment: @magma i'm reading Warner's Introduction to Differentiable Manifolds and Lie Groups: http://www.springer.com/in/book/9780387908946 it's a good book but rather advanced. I'm trying to read it parallel to Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds